# C, How to use exit code properly?

Tags: c, cs50, exit

When I try to submit my work, the system told me to use the exit code. When I use return 0 and recheck, the system told me to use return 1...
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnVLV.png)

```
:) caesar.c exists.  
:) caesar.c compiles.  
:( encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key
    expected "ciphertext: b\...", not "ciphertext: b"  
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
    expected "ciphertext: yx...", not "ciphertext: yx..."  
:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
    expected "ciphertext: ED...", not "ciphertext: ED..." 
:( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
    expected "ciphertext: Fe...", not "ciphertext: Fe..."  
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
    expected "ciphertext: on...", not "ciphertext: on..."
:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using 12 as key
    expected "ciphertext: ia...", not "ciphertext: is..."  
:( handle lack of argv[1]
    expected exit code 1, not 0  
:( handles non-numeric key
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:( handles too many arguments
    expected exit code 1, not 0
```

How can I fix it and what's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int ok;
    char r1;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0, s = strlen(argv[1]); i < s; i++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
            {
                printf("Sorry\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ok = atoi(argv[1]);
                string c = get_string("Enter:");
                printf("ciphertext: ");
                for (int t = 0, a = strlen(c); t < a; t++)
                {
                    if (c[t] < 91 && c[t] > 64)
                    {
                        r1 = (c[t] - 64 + ok) % 26 + 64;
                        printf("%c", r1);
                    }
                    else if (c[t] < 123 && c[t] > 96)
                    {
                        r1 = (c[t] - 96 + ok) % 26 + 96;
                        printf("%c", r1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("%c", c[t]);
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sorry\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I try to do well with my homework and all green...

Comment: Your weird artificial environment apparently expects you to do `return 1;` upon errors. The messages in your picture are pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @Lundin But why there is error?

Comment: `if(argc==2){... } else { printf("Sorry\n");} ... return 0;` clearly doesn't fulfil the related error spelled out to you in the picture. After the "sorry" just do `return 1;` inside the else.

Comment: I like the error output 'expect: bla... not bla...'. It says that it does not expect what it expects. You can tell that the judge is broken. I would almost expect that it would treat "expected exit code 1 not 0" as a success in green.

Comment: By the way this applies to all textual information: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: Try `int main(void) { return 1; }`. Just to debug the judge.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think it's for avoiding little smart ass doing `printf("what the judge say it wanted");` ... Most of time, no human read the source code.

Comment: Your `for (int i = ...` loop looks odd, it has in the `if` and in the `else` a `return 0;`, so it will never iterate a second time. A failing testcase would be `3b` as key.

Comment: @Tom's I do not get your point. Those tricks would be prevented by having two different testcases. One of those test cases *has* to be passed if you output a static copy of what the judge expects for that test case.

Comment: @Yunnosch For example : in my school, we had to code a solution for the chess 8 queen problem. One little smart ass didn't code the solution but rather searched online what was the solution and do a simple "return(92);". He was busted by the prof because he was too quick to solve it, but the "judge" (the script that say if your code is ok or not) give him 20/20. I don't know if i'm clear, english is not my main language.

Comment: You should show the description of the task **as text** in your question. The truncated output of the failed test cases is bad, but the specification of the task might tell how exactly the output should look like. Just a guess: The ```\``` in the message `expected "ciphertext b\...", not "ciphertext b"` might be a truncated `\n`. You could try to append a `\n` after the output to fix the

Comment: @Tom's I know what tricks you meant. I do not know how the strange behaviour of this judge (complaining that they did not expect what they expect) could be seen as a counter measure. At least that is what I understood your first comment to mean. This is hard to discuss with the text we are referring to being a picutre of text which cannot be quoted....

Comment: Does anybody know what Cs50 uses as `string`?  Does this work `string c=get_string("Enter:");`?

Comment: @Yunnosch Because the judge doesn't say completly what he expect. I do agree that this situation would not exist in the first place if the school were to have enougth professor so that every submitted code were readed by a human, but sadly, they use a script to correct and mark student's work ... Fun ending : the professor in my school didn't take kindly what my classmate has done and gave him -42/20 as a final mark

Comment: An Dy Andy. Please show the description of the assignment, as text, in full, directly here. I guess that there is some white space differences between what the judge expects and what you output. Newlines probably. (I agree with @Bodo in saying so.)

Comment: Sorry to have confused you. It is *good* that you edit to provide info and in textual form. However, please make sure that it matches the question as asked, without changing the core. Get the judges textual output, which matches the picture, in here. That would be helpful. Also, for the problematic parts which are not covered yet, especially those after incorporating anything you learned here, you can create a separate question and ask for focused help. Quoting the challenge would also help. Then I think the relevant information is here and makes a decent question.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your friendly reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the exit code by adding a `return <value>,` at the appropriate code line.
With `<value>` being what matches your interface definition, in case of your online judge it seems to be a 1.
In your code you at least fail to do so here:

```
else
    {
        printf("Sorry\n");
    }
```

which should be

```
else
    {
        printf("Sorry\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

An alternative is the more explicit https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit for situations in which the path to the end of the program is not as obvious.

(This is mostly what the comment by Lundin mentions. I turned it into an explicit answer.)

However, to completely satisfy the judge you need to work on your output.
With the info given in the question, a solution for those problems is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- you should return a non zero exit status upon error.
- if the number given as a command line argument has more than 1 digit, you perform multiple iterations (one for each digit). You should move the encoding loop out of the first `for` loop.
- using hard coded ASCII values for upper and lower case letters makes the code less portable and hard to read.  You should use character constants `'A'`, `'Z'`, etc.
- `r1 = (c[t] - 64 + ok) % 26 + 64;` is incorrect and may produce `@` instead of `Z` for some inputs. You should use `r1 = (c[t] - 65 + ok) % 26 + 65;` or better `r1 = (c[t] - 'A' + ok) % 26 + 'A';`
- same mistake for `r1 = (c[t] - 96 + ok) % 26 + 96;`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *arg = argv[1];
    char *p;
    int shift = (int)strtol(arg, &p, 10);
    if (!(arg[0] >= '0' && arg[0] <= '9') || p == arg || *p != '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid shift argument: %s\n", arg);
        return 1;
    }
    char *s = get_string("Enter string: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int t = 0; s[t] != '\0'; t++) {
        unsigned char c = s[t];
        /* assuming ASCII: upper and lowercase letters are contiguous */
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            c = (c - 'A' + shift) % 26 + 'A';
        } else
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            c = (c - 'a' + shift) % 26 + 'a';
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```